# Gstreamer udp-source pcm playback

Tags: gstreamer

I have these gst-launch parameters that do what I want:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc port=22122 ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=16000,channels=1 ! autoaudiosink
```

However, I cannot convert it into code. I'm trying the following:

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("audio-player");

GstBus *bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipeline));
guint bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, bus_call, m_gstMainLoop);
gst_object_unref(bus);

GstElement *source = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "udpsrc0");
GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "autoaudiosink0");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "port", 7200, "buffer-size", 1000000, NULL);
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, sink, NULL);   

GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/x-raw",
                                    "format",   G_TYPE_STRING,  "S16LE",
                                    "layout",   G_TYPE_STRING,  "INTERLEAVED",
                                    "rate",     G_TYPE_INT,     16000,
                                    "channels", G_TYPE_INT,     1, 
                                    NULL);

gst_element_link_filtered(source, sink, caps);
gst_caps_unref(caps);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
g_main_loop_run(m_gstMainLoop);
```

In the dot-graph they look almost alike, but not entirely, though I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but it works if I leave out INTERLEAVED (which should be lower-case if entered) and I also missed that I entered the wrong port-numer (doh!).

Comment: well at least you found this out :) you may consider to close this question as it will not help anybody else.. but this is for your consideration - maybe just that part about interleaved is helpful..

Comment: probably a good idea, but I couldn't figure out how to close the question. Just marked this as answer.

Comment: maybe the info about interleaved can be used for someone.. but in any case you close the question by clicking on light grey "close" its located under the text of question, right under blue tag "gstreamer".. beside options "share" and "edit" ..